# remove master key before migration sql

Tags: sql-server, jobs, ssis-2012

I moved some jobs from sql 2012 to sql 2016, and I got the error:

Environment reference Id: NULL.  Description: Please create a master key in the database or open the master key in the session before performing this operation.  Source: .Net SqlClient Data

I want to delete the master key at source and then script out the jobs and then “paste” them in the new sql 2016. (this could be a ‘fix’, right?)

My questions are:

- How can I delete the master key in the source server?
- Is it a few jobs using this master key, or all of them require this master key?
- Is this “master key” the below? (not sure if the master key is ‘jobs’ or ‘ssis’ level…)
  [image]
- Does the master key has like a login name, or is it just a password?

If deleting the master key (not sure if it is one or many) may be risky… I can try contacting the previous DBA we had, and ask for this password.

Comment: I'd recommend you to find a professional DBA to do this task.

Comment: If I'm reading it correctly, it's telling you to create a matter key at the destination (your 2016 instance). Do you have one there?